# English grammar and confusions

Tags: british-english

Ram and his friends were present there.
V/s 
Ram and his friends was present there.

Comment: What's your confusion? Why do you think one versus the other?

Answer (score 1):

There are two subjects, 1. Ram and 2. his friends therefore the verb is "were".
Poppy Stock

Comment: Ram and not his friends was present there. This is the reason